# How can i use getex and lua for redis

Tags: redis, lua

I have been trying to convert a Lua script that looked like this before:

```lua
local key = ARGV[1]
local ttl = ARGV[2]

local value = redis.call("GET",key)
if value then
    redis.call("EXPIRE", key, ttl)
end
```

to something in which only one `redis.call` is used.
I have seen the use of `GETEX` in Redis CLI but I am not able to use it in Lua script.

I tried:

```lua
return redis.call("GETEX",key,"EX",ttl)
```

and

```lua
return redis.call("GETEX",key,ttl)
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can't reproduce with _7.0.11_ and `return redis.call("GETEX", "somekey", "EX", 5)` loaded into cache. `SET somekey`, `EVALSHA <SCRIPT>`, and then `GET somekey` until `(nil)` works. Can you elaborate on how you execute it and how exactly it doesn't work?

Comment: Also note `GETEX` was added in Redis 6.2, so you'll need a 6.2 or higher Redis server. https://redis.io/commands/getex/

Comment: I am running the commands on redis 6.2.6-alpine-3.15.
I ran eval `"redis.call('GETEX',KEYS[1],'EX',ARGV[1])" 1 b 5` and got
@user_script:1: @user_script: 1: Unknown Redis command called from Lua script .